# How to make a grid layout of CardViews with variable height?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I have multiple `CardView`'s defined in XML as:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_title_material"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

For phones, I have wrapped the multiple `CardView`'s in a vertical `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

For tablets, I would like to use a grid layout instead, similar to the design used in the [Material Design specs](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/cards.html#cards-content), see image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kPPk.png).

What's the best `ViewGroup` to use to make the grid layout? The cards are of variable height, and have static content.

`GridLayout` can't be used, because the cards are of variable height.

Answer (score 1):

For tablets you can use 2 LinearLayouts.