# Image list with text

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to achieve something similar to the attached image

[image: Android Image List]

I was thinking of using *TableLayout* with 2 columns for each row. 
There will be padding in order to be apart of each other. Then I will put white background for the cell. Lastly, I'll just add the *ImageView* and *TextView*.

The images and text are dynamically generated. I will get the image URL and display them.

So, are there any better or more efficient way for implementing what I want to achieve? *TableLayout* doesn't seem to be that efficient.

Comment: Refer https://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html

Comment: try to use a RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager :)

Comment: An ImageView is rather unnecessary. A TextView is enough (top compound drawable + regular text).

Comment: gridview with custom base adapter is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your diagram looks pretty much like a grid - for which you can use a GridLayout in Android: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html

> A layout that places its children in a rectangular grid.
>   The grid is composed of a set of infinitely thin lines that separate the viewing area into cells. Throughout the API, grid lines are referenced by grid indices. A grid with N columns has N + 1 grid indices that run from 0 through N inclusive. Regardless of how GridLayout is configured, grid index 0 is fixed to the leading edge of the container and grid index N is fixed to its trailing edge (after padding is taken into account).

Every one of the items in the grid can be a Cardview (https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) - and that way you will also benefit of a consistent look and feel with Android, without much effort.

Take into account that the cards (every item in the grid) will have the same height, tho: [How to make a grid layout of CardViews with variable height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354943/how-to-make-a-grid-layout-of-cardviews-with-variable-height/31356794#31356794).

If the height of the elements will be variable, you should better take a look to the StaggeredGridLayoutManager: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is use a RecyclerView with a GridLayoutManager.

For a full working implementation: https://inducesmile.com/android/android-gridlayoutmanager-with-recyclerview-in-material-design/